# While Loop vs For Loop, which is more memory efficient!

Tags: java, c

Now that I am used to programming in very memory constraint conditions, one question which I dont have an answer is : Which is more memory efficient;- for(;;) or while() ? Or are they interchangeable equally? Also comment on efficiency matters if any!

Comment: Use the construct that makes sense in your context. I guarantee, your application has bigger efficiency fish to fry.

Comment: I suspect (but don't know) that for(;;) or while(true) compile to the same byte code.  Step 1:  Verify or disprove my suspicion.  Step 2:  If and only if the byte code differs try to figure out which byte code is better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference in memory use between the programming language construct `for` and `while`.  A given compiler might optimize one or the other better but you should not worry about this.  With memory constraint conditions the most important thing is going to be your data structures and system design.  A poor system design could require more memory.

Comment: yes, but when i am using hundreds of such constructs, memory does matter! Anyways thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Purushottam, you can't use hundreds of loops all at once, at least on the same thread. You may have many in your code, but only one can execute at a time. Minor differences in memory consumption will not be a problem no matter which you choose.

Comment: @Purushottam - I doubt it.  If you can save a byte or two (which you can't reliably) even with hundreds you would still save maybe .3k  If you need to do that kind of optimization write it in assembly.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to be sure is to test it with *your* compiler for *your* platform. But I suppose any sufficiently advanced optimizing C compiler would optimize them to the same thing in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(init;cond;inc){
//...
}
```

is (nearly) exactly the same as

```
init;
while(cond){
//...
inc;
}
```

the differences are that `continue;` in the for also executes the `inc;` but you have to do that manually in the while

and the variables declared in the `init;` statement is constrained to the for (it introduces a new scope) however this is not the case in the while

this makes for loops easier to use in several cases (take iteration over an array for example) however the compiled code will likely be the same, so the only reason to choose one over the other is readability

note I'm talking mainly about java I don't know the specifics in c well enough to comment on this

Answer (score 2):

i did some testing in a c program using clock and the results were inconclusive.. so i  wrote the code

```
for(int i=0;i< 100000000; i++){
    g+=2;    
}
```

and the code

```
int i2 = 0;
while(i2 < 100000000){
    g+=2;    
    i2++;
}
```

upon compilation in dev c++ using gcc the assembly breaks down to exactly the same bytecode...

```
CPU Disasm;
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
0040160C  |.  C745 E0 00000 MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.8],0
00401613  |>  817D E0 FFE0F /CMP DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.8],5F5E0FF
0040161A  |.  7F 0D         |JG SHORT 00401629
0040161C  |.  8D45 E4       |LEA EAX,[LOCAL.7]
0040161F  |.  8300 02       |ADD DWORD PTR DS:[EAX],2
00401622  |.  8D45 E0       |LEA EAX,[LOCAL.8]
00401625  |.  FF00          |INC DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]
00401627  |.^ EB EA         \JMP SHORT 00401613
```

both sets of code disassemble to that exact chunk of assembly so as you can see they are equally just as good. this coupled with the clock tests always coming back as one faster one time and the other faster the other time proves it...

if you want efficient you could find your code in a disassembler and optimize it by hand ;)

for example those loops could be represented like this

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
00401492  |.  60            PUSHAD
00401493  |.  31DB          XOR EBX,EBX
00401495  |.  31C0          XOR EAX,EAX
00401497  |>  81FB FFE0F505 /CMP EBX,5F5E0FF
0040149D  |.  7F 05         |JG SHORT 004014A4
0040149F  |.  40            |INC EAX
004014A0  |.  40            |INC EAX
004014A1  |.  43            |INC EBX
004014A2  |.^ EB F3         \JMP SHORT 00401497
004014A4  |>  8945 E4       MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.7],EAX
004014A7  |.  61            POPAD
```

you could change the two INC EAX to ADD EAX,2 but that uses 1 more byte i didnt want to lose :)

this optimization runs about twice as fast :)

Comment: They are always going to look the same in gcc.  If you look at the source code for gcc you will see the semantic tree created is the same -- thus it will produce the same output.  There is no guarantee all compilers will behave thus.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on the compiler... but think of it like this:

```
while(x){
x++;
}
```

uses a variable you declared outside of the scope of the loop, meaning you are using data already made for the loop.

a for loop initializes variables just for the loop inside of the loop.

```
for(int x = 0; x > y; x++{
}
```

So if you have a variable just sitting around that has a value you can use, a while loop would most likely(depends on compiler) be better for that situation. But if you needed to make variables just for the loop, I would use a for loop.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Actually I think it is the reverse.  A simple optimizer will put the index variable (x) in register, while a local variable will be on the stack or in memory.  Both the stack and memory would require more space/resources so the for loop is less likely to be worse.  But the whole thing is so platform / compiler dependent it does not seem even worth discussing.  Still your argument does not hold water because the key is register use not variable initialization.